# Change Tab from Backing bean using JSF 2.0

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, tabview

I want to change tab from backing bean , how can I do that?

```
<h:form id=form>  

    <p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true" />  

    <p:tabView id="tabView" dynamic="true" widgetVar="detailsTab">  

        <p:ajax event="tabChange" listener="#{bean.onTabChange}" update=":form:growl"/>  

        <p:tab title="Tab1" id="emp">  
            <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="10">  


              </h:panelGrid>  
        </p:tab>  

        <p:tab title="Tab 2 " id="schedule1">  
            <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="10">  


            </h:panelGrid>  



        </p:tab>  

        <p:tab title="Tab 3" id="schedule2">  
        <p:schedule value="#{bean.eventModel}" slotMinutes="15" 
                            resizable="false" widgetVar="schdule" initialDate="#{bean.dates}" draggable="true" styleClass="#{bean.selDates}"
                             >
                             <p:ajax event="dateSelect" listener="#{bean.onDateSelect}"
                                update="dialogBox"  oncomplete="patScheduleDialog.show()"/>
                              <p:ajax event="eventSelect" listener="#{bean.onEventSelect}" 
                                update="dialogBox :form:growl" oncomplete="#{bean.pevent}"/>
                                <p:ajax event="eventMove" listener="#{bean.onEventMove}"
                                update="dialogBox, :form:growl" />
                        </p:schedule>

         <p:dialog id="dialogBox" header="Patient's Appointment Details" widgetVar="patScheduleDialog" resizable="true"  
                                 showEffect="explode" hideEffect="explode">  

                <h:panelGrid id="eventDetails" columns="2">  
            <h:outputLabel for="title" value="Title:" />  
            <p:inputText id="title" value="#{bean.event.title}" required="true"/>  

            <h:outputLabel for="from" value="From:" />  
            <p:inputMask id="from" value="#{bean.event.startDate}" mask="99/99/9999">  
                <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" />  
            </p:inputMask>  

            <h:outputLabel for="to" value="To:" />  
            <p:inputMask id="to" value="#{bean.event.endDate}" mask="99/99/9999">  
                <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" />  
            </p:inputMask>  

            <h:outputLabel for="allDay" value="All Day:" />  
            <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="allDay" value="#{bean.event.allDay}" />  

            <p:commandButton type="reset" value="Reset" />  
            <p:commandButton value="Save" actionListener="#{bean.addEvent}" oncomplete="schdule.update();dialogBox.hide();"/>  
        </h:panelGrid>  


    </p:dialog>


        </p:tab>  

    </p:tabView>  


  public void onEventSelect(ScheduleEntrySelectEvent selectEvent){

    // what should I need to do here to set "Tab 2" if click on any event.


    }
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First, you need to set the `activeIndex` attribute of your `<p:tabView>`, like this: `<p:tabView activeIndex="#{bean.selectedTab}">`. It's an `Integer`.

Second, in your bean method, whenever you want to change the active tab, set `selectedTab` to the tab you want to be selected.

Third, remember to update the `<p:tabView>`.

---

You could also do that using JavaScript. Just set the `widgetVar` attribute of your  `<p:tabView>`, like this: `<p:tabView widgetVar="myTabView">`.

Then use the JavaScript function `myTabView.select(tabIndex)`, where `tabIndex` is the index of the tab you want to select.

You can do that at any javascript event, for example: `<p:commandButton oncomplete="myTabView.select(1)" />` would select the second tab after the action of the commandButton completed.

---

Make sure you read [PrimeFaces docs](http://www.primefaces.org/documentation.html).

Comment: The second approach did not worked for me at first.
I had to rewrite it like:
oncomplete="PF('myTabView').select(1)"

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use binding property in a tag p:tabView.

> ```
> <p:tabView id="tabGeneral" binding="#{Bean.tabView}" dynamic="true">
> ```

2. Create Tabview Object in your Bean.

> private TabView tabView;
>
> ```
> public TabView getTabView() {
>   return tabView;
> }
>
> public void setTabView(TabView tabView) {
>   this.tabView = tabView;
> }
> ```

3. Set int like a index in your tabview.

> ```
> tabView.setActiveIndex(0);
> ```

4. Update tabView.

> ```
> RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("tabGeneral");
> ```